# Core Identity Seed User HashPassword failed login

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-identity, .net-5

I have a blazor wasm hosted solution .net5 entity framework and identity core.  I am attempting to seed an admin user with the following

```
public class ApplicationUserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
        {

            #region Seed

            var admin = new ApplicationUser
            {
                Id = "aacc90e3-c1cf-4f04-8bab-3a3498e84904",
                UserName = "TestUser",
                NormalizedUserName = "TESTUSER",
                Email = "Test@Test.com",
                NormalizedEmail = "TEST@TEST.COM",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                LockoutEnabled = false
            };

            admin.PasswordHash = PassGenerate(admin, "P@ssword1");
            builder.HasData(admin);

            #endregion Seed

        }

        public string PassGenerate(ApplicationUser user, string password)
        {
            var passHash = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();
            return passHash.HashPassword(user, password);
        }
    }
```

I have 3 issues

1 - When logging in using the password, it comes back with an invalid login.

2 - The security stamp is an Empty Guid. When registering a user there is always a string present

3 - LockoutEnabled is always 0.  When registering a new user this is always 1

Here is my DBContext OnModelCreating Method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            #region Identity Seed
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new IdentityRoleConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new IdentityUserRoleConfiguration());
            #endregion
            
        }
```

Here is the Configuration of Identity in my Server Startup.cs

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            #region Identity Seed
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new IdentityRoleConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new IdentityUserRoleConfiguration());
            #endregion

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CountryConfiguration());

            
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely based on my stupidity.

1. The user login doesnt work because the login view takes in the email address but passes it to the signinmanager as the username.  Well the username and the email are different.  Stupid me

2 & 3 never update because even though i am changing the content of the configuration i never deleted the migration script and reset the modelsnapshot.  So i kept updating the database with the same original values.

Its been a long day...